# How do I find CSS Selector of slider on webpage?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web

I dont really have any experience with CSS but for a python selenium script im writing I need to figure out how I find the CSS selector of the slider on the bottom of this webpage https://www.publish0x.com/blockchain-insights/millennials-and-crypto-xvwykyo

When I try to use the option 'copy selector' while selecting the element I only get #tipslider which doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem to be it actually...
the `input[type=range]` is a special HTML element which represents a range slider.

you can change the value of it by changing the `value` attribute!

Comment: Do you mind sharing with me how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The #tipslider actually did work.